# How to import data from PostgreSQL database to R?

Tags: r, postgresql, rpostgresql, postico

I'm thinking of importing data from database directly into r using `RPostgresQL` package. So far, I used to write queries in `Postico` (a PostgreSQL client) software and export as csv and then import the csv file into R.
This is what I've written so far and no clue how to proceed next.

```
library('RPostgreSQL')
pg=dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con = dbConnect(pg, user="msahil515", password="",
            host="localhost", port=5432, dbname="msahil515")
```

How do I load tables from the database into R after this or how to write queries in R to extract only necessary data from database?

Comment: `?dbSendQuery` / `?dbGetQuery` I mean, you _have_ to read R manual pages at some point, right?

Comment: @hrbrmstr  Yeah, I tried with    
 `dbWriteTable(con,"some_table_name",table_name,row.names=F)` but I get an error that the object `table_name` not found.

Comment: Why are you using `dbWriteTable()` when your question says you want to load tables and extract data?

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I wasn't even sure if R was connected to the correct database. `dbGetQuery()` worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a straight answer to your question. This definitely can be extended

```
library('RPostgreSQL')

#create connection object
con <- dbConnect(drv =PostgreSQL(), 
                 user="msahil515", 
                 password="",
                 host="localhost", 
                 port=5432, 
                 dbname="msahil515")

dbListTables(con)   #list all the tables 

#query the database and store the data in datafame
first_results <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * from FOO limit 10;")

dbDisconnect(con)   #disconnect from database
```

Comment: Also, i recommend writing your credintials in .Renviron or .Rprofile instead of hardcoding on your credentials on the scripts.

Comment: This answer was close but did not work for me : you need to change the driver name to "PostgreSQL" (as mentioned in the question, this might be a typo).